# Difference between "bieten" and "anbieten"

Tags: difference, verb

Is there a difference between the verbs "bieten" and "anbieten" in sense "to offer"?

Comment: To be able to answer your question we need to know why you had the impression these two distinct verbs are **not** different.

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. Seems like it's the whole reason anyone would use this site

Comment: IMHO questions like this being closed is one reason German Stack Exchange has little traffic. Often a German learner cannot find the answer to this kind of question from most/all bilingual dictionaries because they only say that both verbs mean "offer" and monolingual dictionaries like DWDS or (especially) Duden are overly complex for a non-advanced learner, partly because (1) non-advanced speakers are unable to understand the definitions in monolingual dictionaries and (2) the meanings of a word are not ordered by usage and it's hard to know which meanings are rarely used and could be ignored

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some typical uses where one fits much more than the other: For example one would say:

> Diese (Arbeits-)Stelle bietet ihnen die Möglichkeit, sich persönlich weiterzuentwickeln (*This job offers you the opportunity for personal development*)

IMO nobody would say "anbieten" in this context.
Another case would be such context like offering a seat or refreshments:

> Darf ich ihnen eine Tasse Kaffee anbieten? (*Would you like a cup of coffee?/May I offer you a cup of coffee?*)

Here only "anbieten" fits (I don't know the exact reason, just that I would register "bieten" as odd).

As other answers already stated, there are areas where both are fine.

Comment: Based on https://yourdailygerman.com/meaning-bieten-anbieten/, my understanding is that "bieten" is usually used when it means that something has a feature (e.g. Diese Arbeitsstelle bietet etwas = This job features something; Dieses Haus bietet einen Blick aufs Meer = This house features a view to the sea) and "anbieten" is usually used when someone is offering something to someone else. When money is involved, "bieten" seems usual even if the offer is from a person to another, probably because it can also mean "to bid", which is a similar meaning (e.g. Ich bot Maria 20 Euro für die Kamera).

Answer (score 4):

```
Ich biete Hilfe an.
```

That means *offer help*, with using `anbieten`. Theoretically, you could say the following, too:

```
Ich biete Hilfe.
```

**But** you can say the following:

```
Ich biete 30€ bei der Auktion.
```

Here you can't use `anbieten`, because here, the meaning isn't *offer*.

In general, you can use `bieten` every time you can use `anbieten`, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of bieten can also be `bid, grant` which is not given with anbieten.

Comment: This answer gives only a very narrow view about what *bieten* and *anbieten* mean; which are their shared meanings and which meanings are different.